# Issue <p:ajax> with Dynamic Columns

Tags: primefaces, datatable, dynamic-columns

I am using primefaces 3.5 . I am trying to use `<p:ajax>` with dynamic columns.

`<p:ajax>` does not fire the action I expect.  My code is given below

```
<p:datatable  id = "table">
    <p:columns id="columns" value="#{controller.columnHeaders}" var="columnHeader" >
        <f:facet name="header"> 
            <h:outputText  value="#{columnHeader._label}" />
        </f:facet>
    <p:inputText rendered="#{columnHeader._editable}"
                 value="#{orderController.columnValue}" >
        <p:ajax event = "keyup" update = "table"
                listener = "#{controller.totalRateCalculation}"/>
        </p:inputText>
    <h:outputLabel rendered="#{!columnHeader._editable}"
                   value="#{orderController.columnValue}" />
    </p:columns>
</p:datatable>
```

Anybody help me !!!

Comment: In order to hel, you need to explain what exactly, you expect to happen.

Comment: while entering text in <p:inputText> it should call listener .

Comment: Did you try `<p:inputText rendered="true"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's not the best solution, but you could try using f:ajax instead.

```
<f:ajax event="keypress" render="table"
        "#{controller.totalRateCalculation}">
</f:ajax>
```